# How to make a professional Log in page such as "Tumblr" in Vs 2012 C#

Tags: c#, html, css, visual-studio-2012

Can anyone showS me a tutorial site where I can learn how to make a professional Log-in page such as "Tumblr" using visual studio 2012 C#.
I already know how to make a log-in control but I would like to make it looks more professional such as adding attractive background to the page.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you mess with some HTML and CSS until you get something similar to what you want?

We can help you with the hidden details and bugs, but we are not your personal web developers...

Take a look at these websites with some tutorials on how to do such things:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/16/custom-login-form-styling/

http://www.freshdesignweb.com/css-login-form-templates.html

From there I bet you will be able to develop your own beautiful login page! :)

Comment: Thx for your response and the useful links,however I just asked for sites to learn and improve myself not asked for people to do my work or search for my personal web developers!

Answer (score 0):

Most .NET items like that are created with a template that you have a designer make or buy from a template site. You can use that design and CSS to create both your ASP.NET Master Page and the customized pages, like the login you describe